# Using gsub to replace multiple words in R

Tags: r, regex, string, gsub

I'm getting stuck with trying to normalize a bunch of addresses. Is there a different regex that behaves similar to `\\b\\b` when using `gsub()` but can replace multiple words?

```
address <- c("SE Kellogg", "SE Kellogg Court")
gsub("\\bSE Kellogg\\b", "SE Kellogg Court", address)

#desired output:
"SE Kellogg Court" "SE Kellogg Court"

# actual output
"SE Kellogg Court" "SE Kellogg Court Court"
```

Comment: It is not quite clear. if you want to remove an optional `Court` after `SE Kellogg`, use `gsub("\\bSE Kellogg\\b(?:\\s+Court\\b)?", "SE Kellogg Court", address)`. If any word is to be removed, use `"\\bSE Kellogg\\b(?:\\s+\\w+\\b)?"`. Note that `\b` is a zero-width assertion consuming no text, and can't replace anything by itself. To replace text, you need to consume it with some pattern that meets specified criteria... What are they?

Comment: The problem isn't that there's an optional `Court`, but that my previous `gsub()` introduces an extra one. Is it possible to add a `Court` only to the rows that have `SE Kellogg` but not `SE Kellogg Court`? Thanks for giving it a shot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use a PCRE regex with a negative lookahead:

```
\bSE Kellogg\b(?!\s+Court\b)
```

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SMAAwb/2).

**Details**

- `\\b` - a word boundary
- `SE Kellogg` - a literal substring
- `\\b` - a word boundary
- `(?!\\s+Court\\b)` - a negaive lookahead that fails the match if, immediately to the right of the current location, there are

  - `\\s+` - one or more whitespace chars
  - `Court\\b` - a whole word `Court`.

[R demo](https://ideone.com/smIq8t):

```
> gsub("\\bSE Kellogg\\b(?!\\s+Court\\b)", "SE Kellogg Court", address, perl=TRUE)
[1] "SE Kellogg Court" "SE Kellogg Court"
```

Note you may shorten the replacement if you use a capturing group (`(...)`) around the searchphrase and a `\1` backreference in the replacement pattern:

```
gsub("\\b(SE Kellogg)\\b(?!\\s+Court\\b)", "\\1 Court", address, perl=TRUE)
         ^          ^                       ^^^
```

Comment: This is awesome! Thanks for the detailed answer. I should be able to translate this solution to the remaining mismatching addresses now.

Comment: Just came back to thank you again for seriously saving my ass! Why would people use hand written addresses as their primary key!??? I'd be screwed without this reply.